# Could we get the "new" coding font style?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

As the newest generation of Stack Exchange sites are launched, one thing I'm envious of is the font style used for coding blocks.

Consider the following program here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

Compared to the same program on, say, [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/help-with-query-tuning) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4147/python-code-check-need-help):

[image: Clean fonts for code]

While we don't get a lot of code, the new code style is easier to read and would provide a bit of a contrast to the rest of the text.

Comment: Agreed - I don't think we need the syntax highlighting though, as that would only encourage people to post more code.

Comment: I like the syntax highlighting though. It might not be necessary, but it makes the code look nicer.

Comment: @ChrisF: I like the syntax highlighting. Makes the code less visually bland.

Comment: The font at Code Review is the same as Programmer's. Be honest: you can't tell the difference.

Comment: @sexyprout the font's the same, but the font size is 12px on DBA/Code Review and 14px here.

Comment: I asked for this on SO but the idea was kicked into the long grass. Some of these Object-C code snippets we get there would benefit from a smaller fonts. :(

Comment: The difference between the 2 examples is the font size. On newer sites I decreased the code text size to 12px. Are you asking for a size change? The background colors are a bit different, but only slightly. #eeeeee vs #f3f3f3

Comment: @Jin Yeah, a change in size. The smaller size adds a bit of contrast to the surrounding text and helps mitigate some of the sideways scrolling found in larger code blocks. The shading seems fine (didn't even notice the difference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have decreased the code block font size. This change will be deployed after our next production build.