# The post notice font size has shrunk

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just added a post notice to [a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124109/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-design-patterns) and saw the font had dropped down a size:

> [image: Post notice font problem]

I haven't added a post notice in several days so I don't know when it started doing this, but could it be related to the [change in code block font size](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/could-we-get-the-new-coding-font-style)?

Comment: 99 little bugs in the code, 99 bugs in the code, fix one bug, compile, 100 little bugs in the code.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I heard that just yesterday as “99 little bugs on the wall, 99 little bugs. Take one down, pass it around, 102 little bugs on the wall.”

Comment: @JoshK 102!? Probably someone who still resists unit testing... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [sake of sanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120339/when-did-stack-overflow-start-advertising-for-wikipedia), we recently [switched from using full-blown Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks) to using MarkdownMini (that's the version used in comments and in chat) in post notices.

While full Markdown wraps (almost) everything in `<p>` tags, MarkdownMini does not (since there aren't really paragraphs in comments).

The style rules in the CSS however expect the text to be in `<p>` tags. In the next built, that expectation will be met again.